# Download File (using Thread class)

Tags: winforms, multithreading, stream, httpwebrequest, download

Ok, I understand that maybe very stupid question, but i never did it before, so i ask this question. How can i download file (let's say, from the internet) using Thread class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean with "using Thread class"? I guess you want to download a file threaded so it does not block your UI or some other part of your program.

Ill assume that your using C++ and WINAPI.
First create a thread. [This tutorial](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/multithreaded2.php) provides good information about WIN32 threads.
This thread will be responsible for downloading the file. To do this you simply connect to the webserver on port 80 and send a HTTP GET request for the file you want. It could look similar to this (note the newline characters):

```
GET /path/to/your/file.jpg HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.host.com\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

The server will then answer with a HTTP response containing the file with a preceding header. Parse this header and read the contents.

[More information on HTTP can be found here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

Comment: Yes, I want to not block my program while downloading. I'm a .net beginner, c#, not c++. And as far as i know win32 threads are not the same as .net threads, please, correct me if i wrong. So, start with stupid question. Why i can't make smth like this:
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(someMethod))
void SomeMethod()
{
    code for downloading
}

Comment: Afaik C# threads are wrappers around WIN32 threads.
But that doesnt matter, for sure you can use the method you wrote there. ;)
Simply write your download code in the function you provide to the thread constructor. The code in this method is then executed simultaneously with the rest of your code.
For the downloading part, take a look at Sockets and the HTTP protocol on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

If would suggest that you do not use threads for downloading files. It's better to use asynchronous constructs that are more targeted towards I/O, since they will incur a lower overhead than threads. I don't know what version of the .NET Framework you are working with, but in 4.5, something like this should work:

```
private static Task DownloadFileAsync(string uri, string localPath)
{
    // Get the http request
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri);

    // Get the http response asynchronously
    return webRequest.GetResponseAsync()
        .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                // When the GetResponseAsync task is finished, we will come 
                // into this contiuation (which is an anonymous method).

                // Check if the GetResponseAsync task failed.
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(task.Exception);
                    return null;
                }

                // Get the web response.
                WebResponse response = task.Result;

                // Open a file stream for the local file.
                FileStream localStream = File.OpenWrite(localPath);

                // Copy the contents from the response stream to the 
                // local file stream asynchronously.
                return response.GetResponseStream().CopyToAsync(localStream)
                    .ContinueWith(streamTask =>
                        {
                            // When the CopyToAsync task is finished, we come 
                            // to this continuation (which is also an anonymous 
                            // method).    
                            // Flush and dispose the local file stream. There 
                            // is a FlushAsync method that will flush 
                            // asychronously, returning yet another task, but 
                            // for the sake of brevity I use the synchronous 
                            // method here.
                            localStream.Flush();
                            localStream.Dispose();

                            // Don't forget to check if the previous task 
                            // failed or not.
                            // All Task exceptions must be observed.
                            if (streamTask.IsFaulted)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(streamTask.Exception);
                            }
                        });
                // since we end up with a task returning a task we should 
                // call Unwrap to return a single task representing the 
                // entire operation
            }).Unwrap(); 
}
```

You would want to elaborate a bit on the error handling. What this code does is in short:

See the code comments for more detailed explanations of how it works.